# Force JPA to remove NOT NULL flag after boxing the Entity field

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I use Hibernate with Java, and at some point I had the following entity (simplified):

```
@Entity
public class A {
    private int value;
};
```

I had this class for a long time, and, of course, some rows were added to the database.
But, soon, I changed int to `Integer`(to support nullable on that column).
Now, it looks like as follow:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    private Integer value;
};
```

When JPA creates the column for the `Integer` it makes column `nullable`, but when creates column for `int`, that column has property `NOT NULL`. And that's the same for all boxed types in Java.

But, when I run my app, JPA doesn't remove the `NOT NULL` flag from the already defined schema of the table in the database.
I know that I may remove it manually, but, unfortunately, I described **very** simplified example, and in the real life I have a lot of similar classes with the similar properties.

So, how to force JPA to update the schema correctly and don't loose data already created?

Comment: "schema evolution" is not something covered by current JPA specifications. You are responsible for doing updates to tables that you need, maybe by using your JPA provider to generate the DDL into a file, and then you write an update script to migrate your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The problem*: Changing the schema definition is potentially dangerous, which is probably why JPA does not support changing existing columns. For example if the column width is smaller than the existing one, it could lead to data loss. Also changing a big table on deployment could mean actually long waiting, until the data gets changed (imagine how long you would wait for your change, if it is made on 20 tables, each of 1mln entries).

*Solution*: You will have to do that manually. What I do is keep in my source control system an .sql file (or one for each bigger released feature) that contains all DB changes I have made, so that I know what/when I have to change the DB on production.